# Upgrade openssl to resolve DSA-5139-1 for Docker openjdk:17.0-jdk-slim-bullseye

Tags: docker, security, openssl, debian, openjdk-17

I am using the Debian JDK image in my docker file which introduced a security vulnaribilty DSA-5139-1 [[https://snyk.io/test/docker/openjdk%3A17.0-jdk-slim-bullseye]](https://snyk.io/test/docker/openjdk%3A17.0-jdk-slim-bullseye)

This is my docker file -

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget bash
```

When I build image, it gives me below version of openssl -

```
C:\docker-test>docker run -it openssl_test openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

I tried to install OpenSSL 1.1.1o forcefully but when I get into bash and run openssl version, it always shows me the same version (1.1.1n) -

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get -y remove openssl

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget bash
    
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
```

Then I tried below to force the installation of openssl 1.1.1o but seems "tar" doesn't work -

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get -y remove openssl

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget bash \
    && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1o
    
WORKDIR /openssl-1.1.1o
RUN ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl && make && make install
```

I get this error while building image -

```
#5 12.01 2022-05-20 19:22:46 (3.01 MB/s) - ‘openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz’ saved [9856386/9856386]
#5 12.01
#5 12.01 tar (child): openssl-1.1.1o: Cannot open: No such file or directory
#5 12.01 tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
#5 12.01 tar: Child returned status 2
#5 12.01 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This got worked for me -

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-bullseye

# Perl is required to install openssl
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget bash \
    && apt-get -qy install perl

# Remove current openssl               
RUN apt-get -y remove openssl

# This is required to run “tar” command
RUN apt-get -qy install gcc 

RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install wget make \
    && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz \
    && cd openssl-1.1.1o \
    && ./config \
    && make install

ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/ssl/bin"
```

And this shows the current version -

```
C:\docker-test>docker run -it openssl_test /bin/bash
root@e28ea8c1fb63:/# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022)
```

Comment: This output still shows OpenSSL library version 1.1.1n. Where is vulnerability https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2022-1292/ in 1.1.1n? Does it affect the library or the command-line tool?